# can i include a particular range of variables inside a list datastrucutre

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I wanted to add a particular range of height to the list so I gave it as rang(91,115) but its not working it just prints range(91-115) not the values from 91-115

```
attributes=[[4.10,range(91,115)],[4.10,range(119,138)],[4.10,range(143,186)],[4.10,191]]

physique=["normal","Overweight","obese","Extreme obesity"]
print (attributes)
```

Answer (score 1):

**range** is a *generator*, not a sequence of values.  *You* have to iterate through it.  I suggest a list comprehension appended to the original element, such as:

```
attributes = [
    [4.10] + [_ for _ in range(91, 115)],
    [4.10] + [_ for _ in range(119, 138)],
    ...
]
```